# How to fetch elements with current date in MYSQL when we have only Timestamp field with DateTime values

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a table with field Timestamp(DateTime format). I need to get elements that are entered on the current date. Kindly suggest me a way/query to do so. How to fetch current current date out of the timestamp and compare it with current date via query. HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `curdate()` function

```
select * from table_name where date(col_name) = curdate();
```

Or even better when you have large volume of data and the timestamp column is index and you want index to take into account which will not when you use `date()` function you can do as

```
select * 
from table_name 
where col_name between concat(curdate(),' 00:00:00') and concat(curdate(),' 23:59:59');
```

Comment: not working :(. Note:- the col_name = timestamp(format is DateTime).

Comment: it should work give some example data and the actual column name